# HTTPS shown but website is insecure (apache)

Tags: centos, ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, sharepoint

I'm creating a reverse proxy for my sharepoint site using apache server on CentOS. I added SSL certification but my website shows this:

[image]

Https is shown but my site is insecure!

My sharepoint alternate access mappings are as such:

[image]

How do I make my SSL become secure? Below is the security error for the ssl cert:
[image]

Comment: It's a self-signed certificate which I created on apache itself. I'm using chrome. They show the certificate error `(net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).` @anx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture in your answer answers your question.

Your certificate is not trusted for several reasons the most important of which is that your server signed the certificate. Why should browsers available to people all over the world trust your server to issue an SSL certificate? There are Trusted Root Certificate Authorities. Those are CAs that a web browser trusts to issue SSL certificates. The list varies by browser (and version of browser). I would encourage you to seek out some tutorials on SSL and how Certificates (and Trusted Root Certificate Authorities) work.